# Bootstrap 3 Navbars Layout issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling with the Navbars layout for a project i'm working on. I'm trying to achieve a navbars layout with an image/logo on the left; links on the right but with a login/logout button above the links on the right. I almost get the layout i'm trying to achieve but the heading below the layout always goes particially behind the navbars and i'm not sure how to have the login button above the links on the right.

This is what i'm trying to achieve below (picture attached).
http://1drv.ms/1EkpGbO

// css

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 81px;
  height: 81px;
}
```

// html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                <img src="/Content/Images/logo.png" title="logo" alt="logo" />
            </a> 
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li>
        <span><img src="/Content/Images/login.png" title="login" alt="login" /></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    <header>
<h1>Heading</h1>
</header>
    <hr />
<p>page content </p>
    <footer>
        <p>...</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Could anyone please give me some suggestions on what CSS and HTML needs changing?

Many thanks,
Tarran

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

                <div class="row">
                    <img class="pull-right img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x70">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    <header>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
    </header>
    <hr />
    <p>page content </p>
    <footer>
        <p>...</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1726/

This is just default bootstrap classes, adjust your responsive views

Comment: That appears to be it. Thank you very much. truly appreciate your help.